# Hamburger menu not working on iOS

Tags: html, ios

Do you know issues with the hamburger menu not working on iOS? It works fine from Android, but not iOS for my site http://lastmile-works.com/recruitment/

Here is my code in the header that has menu section

```
<section class="topHeader">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse padding-0">
        <div class="navbar-header toggle-btn clearfix">
            <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".main-navigation">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="Hamburger Hamburger__bar--first"></span>
                <span class="Hamburger Hamburger__bar--middle"></span>
                <span class="Hamburger Hamburger__bar--last"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-lag">
            <ul class="lang-dis">
                <li><a class="lag-en" href="index.html">EN</a></li>
                <li><a  class="lineup-icon" href="#">|</a></li>
                <li><a class="lag-kh" href="index-km.html">KH</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mymenu navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#message">Message</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#aboutus">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#interview">Interview</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#benefits">Advantages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#jobdes">Job Description</a></li>
                        <ul class="lang">
                            <li><a class="lag-en active-lang" href="index.html">EN</a></li>
                            <li><a  class="lineup-icon">|</a></li>
                            <li><a class="lag-kh" href="index-km.html">KH</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: The term Hamburger menu/hamburger icon isn't widely used on iOS. (I was baffled the first time I heard it.) You might want to explain yourself.

Comment: Here is my js you can check it. http://lastmile-works.com/recruitment/js/script.js

Comment: I just checked and it seems to work similarly on both android and iOS.. btw i checked on chrome device mode.. is it specific to any iOS or android version?

Comment: I use iphone5, 5S and iphone6 @Skywalker

Comment: Help me pls i try to fix it but it still not run

Comment: which os version are you using?

Comment: @Thida can you give me your skype id or something.. make some id for getting technical assistance.. you dont want someone tryin to prank you on your personal skype id

Comment: @Skywalker i use ios version 10.3.1 my skype id is thida-pen